# Error : [kapt] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @androidx.room.ColumnInfo does not define an element defaultValue()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

My gradle contain these dependencies

```
implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0'
annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0'
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.0-alpha01"
```

And My model class is

```
    @Entity(tableName = "SubjectDetail")
    public class SubjectDetail implements Parcelable {

        @PrimaryKey
        @SerializedName("id")
        @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
        @Expose
        private int id=0;

        @ColumnInfo(name = "medium")
        @SerializedName("medium")
        @Expose
        private String medium="";

        @ColumnInfo(name = "class")
        @SerializedName("class")
        @Expose
        private String standard="";

        @ColumnInfo(name = "subject")
        @SerializedName("subject")
        @Expose
        private String subject="";

        @ColumnInfo(name = "part1")
        @SerializedName("part1")
        @Expose
        private String part1="";

        @ColumnInfo(name = "partt2")
        @SerializedName("partt2")
        @Expose
        private String partt2="";

        @ColumnInfo(name = "part3")
        @SerializedName("part3")
        @Expose
        private String part3="";

        @ColumnInfo(name = "downloadurl1")
        @SerializedName("downloadurl1")
        @Expose
        private String downloadurl1="";

        @ColumnInfo(name = "downloadurl2")
        @SerializedName("downloadurl2")
        @Expose
        private String downloadurl2="";

        @ColumnInfo(name = "downloadurl3")
        @SerializedName("downloadurl3")
        @Expose
        private String downloadurl3="";

        @SerializedName("created_at")
        @Expose
        @ColumnInfo(name = "createdAt")
        private String createdAt;

        @SerializedName("updated_at")
        @Expose
        @ColumnInfo(name = "updatedAt")
        private String updatedAt;


}
```

Log details

> Task :app:kaptProductionDebugKotlin FAILED e: [kapt] An exception
>   occurred: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   @androidx.room.ColumnInfo does not define an element defaultValue()
>     at
>   com.google.auto.common.AnnotationMirrors.getAnnotationElementAndValue(AnnotationMirrors.java:134)
>     at
>   com.google.auto.common.AnnotationMirrors.getAnnotationValue(AnnotationMirrors.java:114)
>     at androidx.room.ext.Element_extKt.box(element_ext.kt:120)  at
>   androidx.room.ext.Element_extKt.toAnnotationBox(element_ext.kt:166)
>     at
>   androidx.room.processor.FieldProcessor.process(FieldProcessor.kt:42)
>     at
>   androidx.room.processor.PojoProcessor.doProcess(PojoProcessor.kt:171)
>     at
>   androidx.room.processor.PojoProcessor.access$doProcess(PojoProcessor.kt:76)
>     at
>   androidx.room.processor.PojoProcessor$process$1.invoke(PojoProcessor.kt:129)
>     at
>   androidx.room.processor.PojoProcessor$process$1.invoke(PojoProcessor.kt:76)
>     at androidx.room.processor.cache.Cache$Bucket.get(Cache.kt:49)  at
>   androidx.room.processor.PojoProcessor.process(PojoProcessor.kt:126)
>     at
>   androidx.room.processor.TableEntityProcessor.doProcess(TableEntityProcessor.kt:93)
>     at
>   androidx.room.processor.TableEntityProcessor.access$doProcess(TableEntityProcessor.kt:47)
>     at
>   androidx.room.processor.TableEntityProcessor$process$1.invoke(TableEntityProcessor.kt:56)
>     at
>   androidx.room.processor.TableEntityProcessor$process$1.invoke(TableEntityProcessor.kt:47)
>     at androidx.room.processor.cache.Cache$Bucket.get(Cache.kt:49)  at
>   androidx.room.processor.TableEntityProcessor.process(TableEntityProcessor.kt:55)
>     at
>   androidx.room.processor.DatabaseProcessor.processEntities(DatabaseProcessor.kt:286)
>     at
>   androidx.room.processor.DatabaseProcessor.doProcess(DatabaseProcessor.kt:66)
>     at
>   androidx.room.processor.DatabaseProcessor.process(DatabaseProcessor.kt:57)
>     at

Comment: Have you tried removing `kapt` line from your build.gradle? Should only be there if you are using Kotlin in your app.

Comment: I am using Kotlin also in my project.I tried without kapt but I am getting error android - Room + cannot find implementation DB + DB_Impl does not exist  at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

your versions mismatch. defaultValue was introduced in 2.2.0 (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#2.2.0-alpha01)

```
implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.0-alpha01'
annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.0-alpha01'
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.0-alpha01"
```